# fire event when touch up inside uiview and outside button

Tags: iphone, uibutton, touch, accelerometer, camera-overlay

I have a view overlayed to the iPhone's camera view. In this view I have some uibuttons that are displayed in positions depending of values from accelerometer/compass.
I need to fire an event when the user touch up inside the view but he doesn't touch up inside the uibuttons, I mean, the opposite action of touch up inside the uibuttons.
Anyone knows a kind to do this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your options but it doesn't work. The view that I tried to fire the event was in a TabBar item in a camera view, so I think the responders chain doesn't work with it.
Finally, I solved the problem doing the overlay view the first responder with:`[viewOverlay.view becomeFirstResponder];`

Answer (score 1):

If you implement the UIResponder touchesBegan:withEvent: method..

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

...on your view, you'll be able to tell when the user has pressed outside of the buttons.

See the [UIResponder Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

you may e.g. assign one event handler (IBAction) to UiVeiw and its UIButtons and then compare sender parameter:

```
-(IBAction) viewClicked :(id) sender {
  if (id == myView) ...
}
```